# Assembly language programming transfer of control from one segment to another

Tags: assembly

I am unable to understand that first we move CS into SS in line 1 and line 2 but then we assign SS to a completely different value SYSINITSEG (line 3). Why we moved CS to SS when we have to move SYSINITSEG to SS.

```
more code here....... 

MOV AX, CS.              ;line1
MOV SS, AX.              ;line2
MOV SP, OFFSET LOCSTACK

ASSUME SS:SYSINITSEG.      ;line3

LOCSTACK LABEL BYTE

more code here.......
```

Answer (score 2):

Line 3 does not assign anything to SS.  It merely tells the assembler that it should assume that you set SS to the segment `SYSINITSEG`, which the preceding code presumably does.

The assembler needs this information so it can compute offsets to symbols referred to through the SS segment.

Comment: Can we put DS into ES by: MOV ES, DS

Comment: @Vstbutwhy : No you can't copy from one segment register to another directly. You have to copy a segment register to a general purpose register (like AX, BX, CX, DX, DI, SI, BP) and then copy that register to the destination segment register.